# Why does memory allocated from inside a DLL become invalid after FreeLibrary()?

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, dynamic-memory-allocation

I had this bug today which turned out to be because I use a string **allocated from inside my DLL** after calling `FreeLibrary()`.

This is a simple example reproducing the crash. This goes in DLL:

```
void dllFunc(char **output)
{
    *output = strdup("Hello"); // strdup uses malloc
}
```

This is in the EXE that loads the DLL:

```
void exeFunc()
{
    char *output;
    dllFunc(&output);
    std::string s1 = output; // This succeeds.
    FreeLibrary(dll);
    std::string s2 = output; // This crashes with access violation.
}
```

I read the documentation of `FreeLibrary()` but I couldn't find anything about memory becoming invalid after it's called.

**Edit**

I just  realized that I had been using VS2008 toolchain for the DLL while using VS2010 toolchain for the EXE (I was using VS2010 as IDE for both, but you can select the toolchain from the project settings). Setting the toolchain to VS2010 for the DLL as well removed the crash.

Comment: Each DLL is allocated a heap which is released after FreeLibrary()

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you choose static linking with the MSVCRT (C Runtime) library, you will get the behavior you describe. Same thing also happens if your EXE and DLL are dynamically linked to an MSVCRT DLL, but are  using different versions.  Or if they are matched to the same version, but one is using DEBUG and the other is using RETAIL. In other words, memory is only as good as the lifetime of the MSVCRTxxx.dll used to make the allocation. I just saw your update to your question - yes, mixing and matching the CRT between VS 2008 and 2010 is the exact reason for the crash.

If both your DLL and EXE are dynamically linked to the **same** version of the MSVCRT DLL, then you share the memory heap and you avoid the problem you are having.

The standard practice is this: If your exported DLL function returns anything that needs to be "freed" or "released" later, then standard practice is to provide an additional function exported out of the DLL to handle de-allocations.

You can configure both the EXE and DLL's C Runtime linkage from the Code-Generation page for the C/C++ project settings in your project.

Picture here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5K2w4.png

[image]

Comment: Just to add, this would be a private heap, `GetProcessHeap()` returns the same handle regardless of whether it's called from inside the DLL or from the EXE.

Comment: @sashoalm not necessarily. You're not using the Win32 heap functions to allocate memory. You're using `malloc`, which resides in the CRT, and which does quite a bit more than just asking the OS heap for a chunk of memory.

Answer (score 5):

This occurs because each Dll creates its own memory heap (which `malloc` and its C friends, along with `new` will use internally, generally via `HeapAlloc`), and when the Dll is freed, so is its heap.

Refer to [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235460%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more Dll memory caveats. unless you are using a custom memory allocator, shared across all your binaries, you need to keep dynamically allocated memory within the module that created it (unless you can 100% guarantee that the object will not outlive its creator).

Comment: Normally dll does not create it's own heap (unless explicitly doing so by calling HeapCreate or something), it rather uses the heap of a process that loads it. The problem may occur however when executable and dll use different implementations of the same data structures: e.g creation of a subclassed object in a dll and then releasing it in executable may crash, as it will call virtual destructor which has been unloaded along with the dll.

Comment: @Archie: what's your reference for the statement that each DLL uses the process heap?

Comment: @Nik Runtime is responsible for process memory allocation (msvcrt...dll). Both, the dll and executable will share the heap provided by CRT. You can call GetProcessHeap from dll and from executable that loaded that dll, and you will obtain exactly the same handle.

Comment: Yes, if you call `GetProcessHeap` you will get the same handle (since there is *exactly* one process heap) but the question is this: do the low-level memory operations operate on a *private* heap? I don't *know* the answer, but I guess it's easy enough to find out by checking whether a memory allocation by a DLL is in the range of possible memory allocations of the process heap.

Comment: @NikBougalis I just checked and the `GetProcessHeap()` indeed returned the same values when called from both the DLL and the EXE. Also both are Debug builds.

Comment: @Archie: According to MSDN, the CRT creates private heaps ontop of the windows process default heap: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810466.aspx Also, if you want you check heaps, you can walk process private heaps: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee175820(v=vs.85).aspx however, the real point here is that dll shouldn't cross mix memory with the main process or other modules (same goes for TLS data via `__declspec(thread)`).

Comment: It turns out the DLL was built with VS2008 toolchain, while the EXE was built with VS2010 toolchain (I was using VS2010 as IDE for both so it wasn't obvious). When I changed the DLL to be built with VS2010 also, the crash disappeared. So the problem was different versions of the CRT. But thanks for the answer, it pointed me to the right direction. Can you edit your answer (and I'll accept it)?