# How can I release DLL memory inside a Parallel.For?

Tags: c#, memory, dll, unmanaged, parallel.for

In a nested `Parallel.For`, I dynamically load/unload different DLL.
I have noticed that the memory is not released at the end of the 'child' `Parallel.For`. Memory seems to be relased *after* the 'root' `Parallel.For`.

```
Parallel.For(0, 100, j =>
{
     // Do stuffs 

     Parallel.For(0, maxIter, i =>
      {
          // Dynamically load DLL file
          NativeMethods.LoadLibrary(...)

          // Do stuffs with the DLL
          ... (call compute method)

         // Dynamically unload DLL file
         NativeMethods.FreeLibrary(...)
      });

     // Do stuffs 
}

// Do stuffs (DLL Memory seems to be release only here, not before)
```

I've cloned a DLL in many DLL with different names (copy file and rename it).
Each `NativeMethods.LoadLibrary(...)` load one of those DLL. 
The DLL are c++ unmanaged code compiled with `/MD` option. 
Each lib is only used by one thread in the `Parallel.For`

Can you explain that ?

How can I release DLL memory inside a `Parallel.For` ?

Comment: Why are you loading and unloading libraries in a parallel loop in the first place?

Comment: To maximize the free of memory. I really want to understand what's happened in this situation.

Comment: According to [MSDN FreeLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683152(v=vs.85).aspx) decrements reference counting on per-process basis. This implies that library may not get unloaded with call to FreeLibrary if refcount was greater than 1. Hence, clarification questions: How's your `NativeMethods.LoadLibrary` and `NativeMethods.FreeLibrary` are implemented? What libraries are they loading?  Are those unique across parallelization? Is it possible that the same library is concurrently in context of two or more parallels?

Comment: I've cloned a DLL in many DLL with different names (copy file and rename it). Each 'NativeMethods.LoadLibrary(...)' load one of those DLL. The DLL are c++ unmanaged code compiled with /MD option. Each lib is only used by one thread in the Parallel.For

Comment: Is it possible to read 'refcount' ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'memory is not released'?. Like many OSes, Windows caches a lot of things when it sees fit, usually with an overall automatic performance goal in mind. It's not because something is freed from a user/developer standpoint that the memory this "thing" was using behind the scene is actually released at the exact time. In fact, in your case, I think it seems pretty logic to wait for the whole processing stuff to finish before releasing heavy lifted object from memory to not interfere with what you do...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution.

In fact, my native DLL is *dynamically* linked with msvcrt runtime (`/MD` option).

Each time I tried to do `FreeLibrary`, `MSVCRTXXX.dll` are still loaded because its depends of the other loaded DLL.
That's why all unmanaged memory is released after the Parallel.For

This post helped me a lot : [Why does memory allocated from inside a DLL become invalid after FreeLibrary()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300812/why-does-memory-allocated-from-inside-a-dll-become-invalid-after-freelibrary)

I've just recompiled my native DLL with *static* link to msvcrt runtime.

Now memory is perfectly relased after 'FreeLibrary' call :-)