# Memory issue with using C++ Protobuf in a DLL

Tags: c++, windows, dll, protocol-buffers

This question was posted on Google Group's Protobuf group but unfortunately it has gone unanswered.

A DLL has been created that will accept any Protobuf message which through the use of reflection will be filled with data from a database and then returned to the client. The database table name is mapped to the message name and the corresponding table columns are mapped to the message member names.

The issue appears to be with the 'SetString' method of the reflection class. After the call to the DLL has been made and the protobuf message with all the relevant has been received, a memory error is encountered as the program exists.

A typical message will have a .proto file such as the following:

```
message OperatingSystemInfo {
   string manufacturer;
   string name;
   string release;
   string osversion;
   string localename;
   string bootdevice;
   string serialnumber;
}
```

The code snippets for the DLL functions are as follow:

```
void EXPORT_DLL ReadMessage(void* protoBufMessage) {

      Message* msg = static_cast<Message*>(protoBufMessage);
    
      const Descriptor* descriptor = msg->GetDescriptor();
      const Reflection* reflection = msg->GetReflection();
    
      for (int i = 0; i < descriptor->field_count(); i++) {
    
        const FieldDescriptor* field = descriptor->field(i);
        const FieldDescriptor::Type type = field->type();
        bool isRepeated = field->is_repeated();
    
        std::string name = field->name();
    
                           
        if (type == FieldDescriptor::TYPE_MESSAGE) {
    
        }
        else {
           //read values from database for each corresponding field and set value
           string fieldValue;
    
           SetFieldValues(reflection, field, msg, fieldValue);
        }
    }

}
```

```
void SetFieldValues(const google::protobuf::Reflection reflection,
const google::protobuf::FieldDescriptor field,
google::protobuf::Message msg,
std::string fieldValue) {

              switch (field->type()) {
                 case FieldDescriptor::TYPE_STRING:
                    reflection->SetString(msg, field, move(fieldValue))
                 break;
    
                 case FieldDescriptor::TYPE_UINT32:
                 break;
    
                 case FieldDescriptor::TYPE_UINT64:
                 break;
         
                 case FieldDescriptor::TYPE_BOOL:
                 break;
    
                case FieldDescriptor::TYPE_ENUM:
                break;
    
                default:
                break;
    
              }

}
```

The client call to the DLL is:

```
void CallDLL()
{
    OperatingSystemInfo* osi = new OperatingSystemInfo();

    ReadMessage(osi);
    
    delete osi;

}
```

The problem is that when the application is about to terminate, the 'Destroy' method for the last string in the message, 'serialnumber', causes a memory error (__acrt_first_block == header in debug_heap.ccp):

```
inline void OperatingSystemState::SharedDtor() {
    GOOGLE_DCHECK(GetArenaForAllocation() == nullptr);
    _impl_.manufacturer_.Destroy();
    _impl_.name_.Destroy();
    _impl_.release_.Destroy();
    _impl_.osversion_.Destroy();
    _impl_.localename_.Destroy();
    _impl_.bootdevice_.Destroy();
   _impl_.serialnumber_.Destroy(); 
}
```

```
void ArenaStringPtr::Destroy() {

        //Line 233 in arenastring.cc 
        //leads to assertion Expession: __acrt_first_block ==  header in debug_heap.ccp
        delete tagged_ptr_.GetIfAllocated();
}
```

Naturally this is an attempt to free an already freed memory.  It is likely that allocating the memory outside of the DLL is a factor but the nature of the project is such that the DLL has no knowledge of Protobuf message types. Hence the reason that reflection is used.

Any helps or hints in resolving this issue is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The only fix at the moment is to set the string fields in the message to blank before sending it to the DLL.  For example:

osi->set_serial_number("");

This would make sense as the memory is allocated and then de-allocated on the client side.

Comment: Do both the DLL and the client link with the same CRT?

Comment: @ssbssa Yes, they do.

Comment: Static or dynamic linking?

Comment: Static linking.

Comment: That explains it, you need to link dynamically to the same CRT if you want to be able to free a memory block that was allocated in a different DLL/executable (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15308186/1983398)).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @ssbssa. I apologize for the tardy reply. Just to be clear, I assume by 'static or dynamic linking', you are referring to VS' 'C/C++ | Code Generation ] Runtime Library.'  If so, then there is no choice but to link Protobuf based applications statically. To reiterate, both the DLL and the client are linked statically.

Comment: But why do you link the Runtime Library statically?

Comment: This is what the Protobuf build instructions recommend :
https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/main/cmake/README.md

"Static linking is now the default for the Protocol Buffer libraries. Due to issues with Win32's use of a separate heap for each DLL, as well as binary compatibility issues between different versions of MSVC's STL library, it is recommended that you use static linkage only."

I will probably create a seperate build and create the Protobuf DLLs to see  if this fixes the issue.  Thanks again for your assistance, @ssbssa.

Comment: Yes, it recommends static linking of the protobuf library, so you shouldn't even have a DLL in the first case. But it's not telling you to link the CRT statically.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "so you shouldn't even have a DLL in the first case." The 'README.md' states: 'If your project is itself a DLL intended for use by third-party software, we recommend that you do NOT expose protocol buffer objects in your library's public interface, and that you statically link protocol buffers into your library.'

In regards to the switches '/MT' (Multi-threaded) or '/MD' (Multi-threaded DLL), the problem is that '/MD' causes a plethora of link errors with the Protobuf libraries.  I will attempt to create the Protobuf DLLs and then use the '/MD' switch.

Comment: Yes, so you go against that recommendation, since you DO expose your protocol buffer object, in this case you expose the object from the client to the DLL.

Comment: No, no Protobuf objects are exposed in the DLL interface. The interface accepts just a 'void *' object which is then sent to a PImpl object. There it is cast to a generic Protobuf message. For the sake of brevity and simplicity, I omitted the PImpl implementation and its corresponding code.  What you see above in the 'ReadMessage' function has been greatly simplified in order to place the focus on the relevant Protobuf APIs.

Comment: I don't understand what your point is. If you're exposing the protobuf object, then you're doing exactly what you're not supposed to do according to the recommendation.

Comment: As I explained in detail, there is no exposure of  Protobuf objects in the DLL interface.  The actual code is ReadMessage(void *obj) { pImpl->ReadMessage(obj) }. The casting of the void pointer to a Protobuf object takes place within the PImpl class which is outside of the DLL's public interface as recommended in the Protobuf ReadeMe file. The DLL interface's header file contains no '#include.' Again, as I stated previously, I omitted these details in the original post for the sake of brevity and placing the focus on the relevant code.

Comment: Who does `OperatingSystemInfo* osi = new OperatingSystemInfo();`, the client or the DLL?